# delete a char in a string

Tags: c++, string

I need to delete a specified location in a string

For  example:

input: 4 Flower

output: Floer

I wrote this code but it gave an output: Flo (i.e. erased the rest of the word)
What other function, instead of erase, can I use to achieve this objective?

```
int main(){

    int num;
    int index = 1;
    string s;

    cin >> num >> s;
    s = s.erase(num-1);
    cout << index << " " << s << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Try:

```
s.erase(num-1, 1);
```

You are currently (effectively) calling:

```
s.erase(num-1, npos);
```

(and remove the `s =` bit as there is no need to reassign `s`).

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner in C++ world, I would suggest you to write your own function that does it! You may use standard functions and classes anytime you would need. Some may say, why to re-invent the wheel, but its not about re-invention, but learning what invention mean, what wheel is, and how it was invented.

Writing our own code (specially for C-strings!) will give your very good programming experience, will give confidence about syntax, and most imporatantly it will enhance your logic development skills.

Your function may be like:

```
void RemoveCharacter(char* pString, char cCharToRemove);
```

Now, the question is: will it remove all occurrences of same character, or just the first one? What if there are no occurrence of given character? 
Should this function return something, if it removed character, or a counter of removals? Should it take another parameter, which says "remove-all-occurrences" or not.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
std::string removeChar(std::string const& input, size_t pos) {
    return input.substr(0, pos-1) + input.substr(pos);
}
```

or this

```
std::string removeChar(std::string const& input, size_t pos) {
    return input.erase(pos-1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try
`s.erase(num-1, 1)`, this is what you want.

The prototype of std::string::erase is

```
erase(size_t __pos = 0, size_t __n = npos)
```

If the second parameter is not supplied, the default value `npos` will be used and the remainder started from __pos will be removed.